# Old Date Formatting incompatible with Java 8 ZonedDateTime API

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-8

I am updating my old date formatting code to Java 8 and trying the **ZonedDateTime API**.

The format of date is same as the Javascript Date object format, e.g. -

> Thu May 25 2017 10:00:00 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard Time)

I was using the below format previously -

> EEE MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss 'GMT'Z '('zzzz')'

This format fails to parse the date string using **DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern** method.

Here's the code:

```
public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "EEE MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss 'GMT'Z '('zzzz')'";

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String sDate = "Thu May 25 2017 10:00:00 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard Time)";
    parseDate(sDate);
}

private static void parseDate(String sDate) throws ParseException {

    // works
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
    Date oldDate = dateFormat.parse(sDate);

    //FIXME: can't parse?!
    ZonedDateTime newDate = ZonedDateTime.parse(
           sDate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT)); // <- this is the line 25!
}
```

Here's my full code for reference that can be compiled and run - https://gist.github.com/bhabanism/470e03db54981ad6ddedbba316dcaa9a

This fails at line#25 with:

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
>   Text 'Thu May 25 2017 10:00:00 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard Time)'
>   could not be parsed: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from
>   TemporalAccessor: {HourOfAmPm=10, MilliOfSecond=0, MinuteOfHour=0,
>   OffsetSeconds=43200, MicroOfSecond=0, NanoOfSecond=0,
>   SecondOfMinute=0},ISO,Pacific/Auckland resolved to 2017-05-25 of type
>   java.time.format.Parsed

Note, I can't change the input format of the Date, it has to be

> Thu May 25 2017 10:00:00 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard Time)

I can surely modify the formatter

> EEE MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss 'GMT'Z '('zzzz')'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there was a bug in your format string all the time. Lowercase `hh` is for hour within AM or PM, in the range 1 through 12. Since you don’t have AM/PM in your string, I suspect this was never what you wanted, and I wonder how the error went unnoticed.

Uppercase `HH` is for hour of day, 0 through 23:

```
public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z '('zzzz')'";
```

With this change both the old and the new way of parsing works on my computer.

When adding `Locale.ENGLISH` to both formatters, that is. You may want to do the same.

The results I get are

```
Thu May 25 00:00:00 CEST 2017
2017-05-25T10:00+12:00[Pacific/Auckland]
```

Since CEST is 2 hours ahead of UTC, this is the same point in time, only rendered differently.

Comment: Thanks, this works!  Looks like this bug existed for a long time, no idea how so many unit tests kept passing!

Comment: So you’ll be sure to write one now that fails. Happy to help.

Comment: Just came to think, writing a failing test for `hh` is not that trivial. Parsing, say, 17 hours or 0 hours will probably give the expected result with a lenient `SimpleDateFormat`. You may `setLenient(false)` and it should fail. And you may try *formatting* an hour outside 0 through 12, and it will fold it into that interval.

Comment: Yes, will try that

Comment: For a test that fails with lower case `hh` parse a string where the hour is `12`. `SimpleDateFormat` will assume 12 AM and parse into 00.